# Adding column with default values to temp table when using two stored procedures to populate the temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that executes two stored procedures and gets the correct data, but now I need to add a column into the temp table with default values.

e.g I want to add a Location type column to the temp table when the first stored procedure executes i want to add 1 to each record and when the second stored procedure is added to the temp table I want to add 2 to this column for each record. Can this be achieved?

Nothing much more

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspStockAdjustmentGetStorageLocationTESTDELETEAFTER]
    @CategoryId INT,
    @ReasonId INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @LocationType INT

    SELECT @LocationType = LocationType
    FROM [dbo].[StockAdjustmentReasonGLAccount] 
    WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId AND ReasonId = @ReasonId

    IF(@LocationType = 1)
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #tmp
        (
             ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
             CODE NVARCHAR(50), 
             Description NVARCHAR(50) 
        )

        INSERT INTO #tmp 
            EXECUTE dbo.uspStockAdjustmentWorkCentreSelectAll 

        INSERT INTO #tmp    
            EXECUTE dbo.uspStockAdjustmentGetSAPStorageType

        SELECT 
            Code, MIN(id) AS Id  
        FROM 
            #tmp 
        GROUP BY
            CODE 
        ORDER BY 
            Id

        DROP TABLE #tmp
    END
```

I am not sure on how to add this column with the default values

Comment: Define the column with a `DEFAULT` value. [Specify Default Values for Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If you are just going to immediately update the value to 2 after the second procedure runs I don't see why you are bothering with a value of 1. Just add an update after the second procedure call. Update #tmp set LocationType = 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the temp table with the new column with default value as 2

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    ID   INT IDENTITY(1,1) , 
    CODE nvarchar(50), 
    Description nvarchar(50),
    LocationType INT default 2
)
```

specify the column explicitly when insert into the temp table.

```
INSERT INTO #tmp (CODE, Description)
EXECUTE dbo.uspStockAdjustmentWorkCentreSelectAll
```

change the LocationType to 1 after first stored procedure executes

```
UPDATE #tmp
SET    LocationType  = 1

INSERT INTO #tmp (CODE, Description)   
EXECUTE dbo.uspStockAdjustmentGetSAPStorageType
```

result from second stored procedure will have the value 2

Comment: did you include the LocationType when you create the #tmp table ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the code you have been provided, @danielcarey; that's an error in your SP that we don't have the definition for.

Comment: That worked. Many thanks. You have saved me from hours of headache